# Double checking if contours are correct

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Since

$$ |z| = 1 $$

is the unit circle centered at (0,0) which is used as a contour for a lot of integration problems, would

$$ |z - i| = 1,   |z + 3| = 1 $$

simply be translations of the unit circle, with the first one centered at (0,-i) and the next one at (3,0)?

Comment: So, what is the question? The centers should be at $(0,i)$ and $(-3,0)$ though, since filling in $i$ in $|z-i|$ gives $0$, and similarly for $|z+3|$.

Comment: If that is correct or not, oh right (-3,0) but I thought for y axis should be correct?

Comment: I believe you're over thinking this. It's analogous to the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you demand $|z-i|=1$, then the circle is centered at $z=i$, as $|i-i|=0$. So you can imagine that it's like moving 'up' to $i$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and then sweeping out a circle of radius $1$ there.

Comment: Oh I see, I was thinking that since y = x^2 + 1 is a translation up, this should be translation down. But it is actually y - 1 = x^2 so now I understand, thanks both.